# Synchronizing the UI Thread with a Method Called on another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have an application which can work on offline/online mode.When it goes online from offline mode it perform some synchronization with server. The synchronization is done in a thread to make UI responsive.

My problem is that whenever I invoked any server func say A() in offline mode.It performs synchronization and return control to main thread which will start executing A, and it is causing some issues in data sync.

I have to wait for thread to  complete i.e synchronization from server and then execute method A(). How can I do that. Synchronization from server must be done on thread I cannot move it into main thread.

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Are you using the .NET 4.0 Task Parallel Library?

Comment: Sounds like continuation-passing :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you're done with the synchronization, notify the main thread it should call execute A. If you're using WPF, use a `Dispatcher` (each UI thread has one)